# Is there a natural language web application framework?

Tags: nlp, programming-languages

Is there a natural language web application framework? Maybe something like http://inform7.com ?

Maybe something like:

Make a website called My_homepage at my_homepage.com
The homepage for My_homepage is called mainpage
mainpage has a title of 'Home'
mainpage has text at the top saying 'My homepage'

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about what you mean?

Comment: I guess I mean something a non technical person could learn to use

Comment: You see, this is the problem here. A non technical person cannot learn to use it by only reading natural language. He still has to understand exactly what it does and why. For example, what if you write the Dijkstra algorithm an natural language. Will your mother or father understand it ? I believe - no.

Comment: Do you need the Dijkstra to write a web page. Sorry, I didn't know that.

Comment: I give you an example ... If you make a web page that is a little more than just a static content, you will have to implement some algorithms or properly used already written implementation. If, on the other hand, you page is "static" you can use WYSIWYG editor. I believe it's really natural even for non technical person.

Comment: Most of the non technical people I know can just about get around HTML, but even that is pretty difficult for them according to what they say to me.

Comment: Also, what sort of algoritms are needed for web sites?

Comment: Well ... it depends on what services you plan to provide in your site ...

Comment: Backend and database services as well as just web pages

Comment: no i mean what business services. From example a search engine site, a  social network, stackoverflow2 :) ... you know. What your site is going to do for his visitors.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Yes, the sort of thing that could be used to build a site with complexity like stackoverflow

Comment: (This popped up due to the new answer.) You're basically describing a DSL; the skeleton of a web app could be generated pretty easily from a description like this. Getting in to actual functionality would almost certainly require something beyond a trivial DSL, although for simple CRUD stuff you could get pretty far without a Herculean effort.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean "Is there a framework for developing web application in natural language?" - no there isn't.

And not only for web application. The natural language is way too complicated to be understand with no duplication of meanings. The syntax is not strictly defined and so on ... In fact we people have difficult times understanding each other :)

You cannot write a formal grammar on natural language that fits in hierarchy of Chomsky. Even the C/C++ grammar is very complicated. (it's Context-sensitive I believe).

Actually I think that not the programming languages are difficult to understand in fact. The algorithms and the concept of programming, the semantic that those programming languages have is more important.

Comment: But you can write a web application without knowing C?

Comment: Couldn't a formalised subset of natural language be used, something which is easy to read?

Comment: @Zubair Even just that has been tried before. Being "readable by managers" was the argument for COBOL, and AppleScript tries to be readable by non-programmers too. But programs are harder to write in both these languages, and programmers tend not to like them.

Comment: @Pascal: right idea, but COBOL is no harder to use than any other language of its time. The issue with COBOL is that its time is so far past.

Comment: By subset you should not only limit the words that are used. You should reduce the number of rules that construct valid constructions. In fact ... most of the programming languages are formalized subset of natural languages. Take Visual Basic for example, it's very near to the real language (not so near to developers, though).

Comment: I didn't know about Cobol being human readable. Do you know any good web links I could use to read up on this, as maybe Cobol will be my answer. Thanks

Comment: And I'm quite happy with old languages, Erlang for example. Its the new languages I worry about as stable and battle tested languages are more for me.

Comment: @John Some LISPers might disagree, but then some non-LISPers might disagree with the LISPers :)

Comment: @Zubair If you are going to try COBOL as a result of my comment, it means I have completely failed to get my point across. Is THIS really what you want? http://www.infm.ulst.ac.uk/~ted1/html/cobol.htm

Comment: I looked at the Cobol example you showed me and I know what you mean. I guess its a classic case of someone "marketing" cobol as "readable by managers" but not being the case in real life. I agree with you :)